# Count the number of Files assigned each month only if in current year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a date column which is labeled "Date Assigned" and I want to total the number of occurrences of a certain month (which represents how many files I assigned that month) only if it's in the current year.

I've made a pick list of all the months and I want to be able to pick month and have it calculate the number of occurrences of that month in that column if we are in the current year.

I tried doing this but it didn't work. I must not be using the year or today functions correctly

```
=IF(B9="October",IF(YEAR(TODAY()),(COUNTIFS(Active!F:F,">=1/10/2014",Active!F:F,"<=31/10/2014")),0),0)
```

I'm using excel 2007

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts, possibly by using an unregistered account across multiple devices. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them you will need to provide links to the two accounts, for your information these are http://superuser.com/users/380347/brandy and http://superuser.com/users/380350/branbran. You'll then be able to edit, comment on and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I put your exact query into Excel (though i only have access to 2013, but doubt there should be a difference) and it works. Picks out the dates in October, and doesn't pick 2013

Show what error you are getting

[image]

Comment: unfortunately I'm not getting an error. I have only 2 dates in that column right now and I changed the year of one of them to be 3/10/2015 and when I re-chose October from my picklist, it doesn't seem to change the result to 1 instead of 2. I thought picking a new item in my month picklist would make the forumula re-run. Am I missing something?

Comment: Long shot but try hitting F9 incase your automatic recalculate formulas setting is off. (Can turn it back on in options if that's the case)... If not then can you upload the sheet somewhere? or take out what you need and upload it. I would have to see it